# How to use css selector using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

A jQuery for, on HTML page load, call a function which will set a text "Hello world!" on all the labels which have got the css "hello".

Can someone tell me a little bit about this?

Comment: a quick google search could have helped you.

Comment: and what is "css hello"? Take some time to read [ask] and do some basic research before asking questions

Comment: Its good  for you to get a revision on html before going for j query!

Comment: i am not getting bro... i know html but beginner in jquery

Comment: we don't get it either if you don't write an understandable goal and question and provide relevant html structure

Answer (score 1):

To select all elements with the class hello. on HTML page ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hello").each(function(index){
        /* do stuff */
    });
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".hello").each(function(index){
    $(":label").css("background-color","yellow");
   });
  });

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $(".hello").Text("hello world"); });
```

If still doesn't work check whether your jQuery is loaded

Comment: Text must be lowercase and he wants to run code for each one, not change it's text.